# C | Рекурсивное вычисление arctg(x)

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия, непрерывные-дроби

Требуется вычислить arctg x с помощью рекурсивной функции и цепной дроби:
[image: Текст]

С точностью 0,000001.
Делаю так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#define ALPH 0.000001

double myatan_r(double x, double n)
{
    if ((n - 1) * exp(1) - (n * exp(1)) <= ALPH && n != 0) return 1;

    return (2 * n + 1) + ((((n != 0) ? (n * n) : (1)) * x) / myatan_r(x * x, (n != 0) ? (n * 2) : 2));
}

double myatan(double x)
{
    return  x / myatan_r(x * x, 0);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Write x: ");
    float x = 0;
    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("Default atan rez: %lf\n", atan(x));
    system("pause");
    printf("My atan rez: %lf\n", myatan(x));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но мне выкидывает исключение о переполнении стека. Как фиксить и что именно не так?

Comment: обеспечьте, чтобы первое условие выполнялось. У вас оно никогда не выполняется.

Comment: Именно рекурсивной функцией, или с помощью рекуррентного соотношения?

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите добиться условием `if ((n - 1) * exp(1) - (n * exp(1)) <= ALPH && n != 0) return 1;`? Член `n^2*x^2/(2n+1) только растет с увеличением n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гм. Рекурсивно - неприятно, откровенно говоря. Ну, на коленке, используя формулы для частичных сумм непрерывной дроби, и очень, очень неэффективно - просто набросок:

```
double Pn(int n, double x)
{
    if (n == -1) return 1;
    if (n == 0)  return 1;
    return (2*n+1)*Pn(n-1,x)+ n*n*x*x*Pn(n-2,x);
}

double Qn(int n, double x)
{
    if (n==-1) return 0;
    if (n == 0)  return 1;
    return (2*n+1)*Qn(n-1,x)+ n*n*x*x*Qn(n-2,x);
}

double ratn(double x, int n)
{
    return x*Qn(n,x)/Pn(n,x);
}

double atan(double x, double eps)
{
    double res = 0;
    for(int n=2;;n++)
    {
        double res2 = ratn(x,n);
        if (fabs(res-res2) < eps) return res2;
        res = res2;
    }
}
```

Плохо то, что много раз считаем одно и то же, но, честное слово, лень переписывать сложно, но эффективно... Вот - [работает](https://ideone.com/OW0Y8h)...

Куда более эффективно итеративно, но с использованием рекуррентного соотношения:

```
double atan(double x, double eps)
{
    double p1 = 1, p0 = 1;
    double q1 = 0, q0 = 1;

    double at = x*q0/p0;

    for(int n = 1; ; ++n)
    {
        double z0 = 2*n+1, z1 = n*n*x*x;
        double p = p0*z0+z1*p1;
        double q = q0*z0+z1*q1;
        double r = x*q/p;

        if (fabs(at-r) < eps) return r;
        at = r;
        p1 = p0; p0 = p;
        q1 = q0; q0 = q;
    }
}
```